# Shotcut does not show in App Grid

Tags: icons, snap, video-editor

I have Shotcut video editor installed from the snap, all was well until I noticed a day or so ago that it no longer shows up in the app grid of my Gnome desktop (17.10). Nor does it show up if I search for it in the activities window. I can only launch it from the terminal.
There are a lot of icon generation `WARNING:` messages when I run it, I wonder if this is related? Any help would be welcome, thank you!

```
cp: /home/brodie/.config/user-dirs.locale' and '/home/brodie/.config/user-dirs.locale' are the same file
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/Adwaita
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/hicolor
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/Humanity
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/Humanity-Dark
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/LoginIcons
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/breeze_cursors
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/Breeze_Snow
/snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: 16: /snap/shotcut/22/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: not found
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/icons/default
No appenders registered with logger
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> language "en_GB" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> deinterlacer "onefield" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> external monitor "" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> GPU processing false 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> interpolation "nearest" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> video mode "" 
[Debug  ] <ShotcutSettings::singleton> realtime true 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> Starting Shotcut version 18.05.03 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> Linux version 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> number of logical cores = 4 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> locale = QLocale(English, Latin, UnitedKingdom) 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> install dir = "/snap/shotcut/22/Shotcut.app/bin" 
[Info   ] <Application::Application> device pixel ratio = 1 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::changeTheme> begin 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::changeTheme> end 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::MainWindow> begin 
[Info   ] <GLTestWidget::GLTestWidget> OpenGL context version 2 1 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::Controller::Controller> begin 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::Controller::Controller> end 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::GLWidget::GLWidget> begin 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::GLWidget::GLWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::setupSettingsMenu> begin 
libDeckLinkAPI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Warning] <MLT> [ 0x247c010] The DeckLink drivers not installed.
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::setupSettingsMenu> end 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::readPlayerSettings> begin 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::setAudioChannels> 2 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::Controller::setAudioChannels> 2 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::readPlayerSettings> end 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::configureVideoWidget> begin 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::setProfile> "" 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::Controller::setProfile> setting to profile "Automatic" 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::setAudioChannels> 2 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::Controller::setAudioChannels> 2 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::configureVideoWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeController::ScopeController> begin 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> begin true 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <AudioLoudnessScopeWidget::AudioLoudnessScopeWidget> begin 
[Debug  ] <AudioLoudnessScopeWidget::AudioLoudnessScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> begin true 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <AudioPeakMeterScopeWidget::AudioPeakMeterScopeWidget> begin 
[Debug  ] <AudioPeakMeterScopeWidget::AudioPeakMeterScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> begin true 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <AudioSpectrumScopeWidget::AudioSpectrumScopeWidget> begin 
[Debug  ] <AudioSpectrumScopeWidget::AudioSpectrumScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> begin true 
[Debug  ] <ScopeWidget::ScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <AudioWaveformScopeWidget::AudioWaveformScopeWidget> begin 
[Debug  ] <AudioWaveformScopeWidget::AudioWaveformScopeWidget> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <ScopeDock::ScopeDock> end 
[Debug  ] <ScopeController::ScopeController> end 
[Debug  ] <RecentDock::RecentDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <RecentDock::RecentDock> end 
[Debug  ] <PlaylistDock::PlaylistDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <PlaylistDock::PlaylistDock> end 
[Debug  ] <TimelineDock::TimelineDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <TimelineDock::TimelineDock> end 
[Debug  ] <FiltersDock::FiltersDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <FiltersDock::FiltersDock> end 
[Debug  ] <KeyframesDock::KeyframesDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <KeyframesDock::KeyframesDock> end 
[Debug  ] <EncodeDock::EncodeDock> begin 
---
formats:
  - a64
  - ac3
  - adts
  - adx
  - aiff
  - amr
  - apng
  - asf
  - ass
  - ast
  - asf_stream
  - au
  - avi
  - avm2
  - bit
  - caf
  - cavsvideo
  - crc
  - dash
  - data
  - daud
  - dirac
  - dnxhd
  - dts
  - dv
  - eac3
  - f4v
  - ffm
  - ffmetadata
  - fifo
  - filmstrip
  - fits
  - flac
  - flv
  - framecrc
  - framehash
  - framemd5
  - g722
  - g723_1
  - g726
  - g726le
  - gif
  - gsm
  - gxf
  - h261
  - h263
  - h264
  - hash
  - hds
  - hevc
  - hls
  - ico
  - ilbc
  - image2
  - image2pipe
  - ipod
  - ircam
  - ismv
  - ivf
  - jacosub
  - latm
  - lrc
  - m4v
  - md5
  - matroska
  - matroska
  - microdvd
  - mjpeg
  - mlp
  - mmf
  - mov
  - mp2
  - mp3
  - mp4
  - mpeg
  - vcd
  - mpeg1video
  - dvd
  - svcd
  - mpeg2video
  - vob
  - mpegts
  - mpjpeg
  - mxf
  - mxf_d10
  - mxf_opatom
  - null
  - nut
  - oga
  - ogg
  - ogv
  - oma
  - opus
  - alaw
  - mulaw
  - f64be
  - f64le
  - f32be
  - f32le
  - s32be
  - s32le
  - s24be
  - s24le
  - s16be
  - s16le
  - s8
  - u32be
  - u32le
  - u24be
  - u24le
  - u16be
  - u16le
  - u8
  - psp
  - rawvideo
  - rm
  - roq
  - rso
  - rtp
  - rtp_mpegts
  - rtsp
  - sap
  - scc
  - segment
  - stream_segment,ssegment
  - singlejpeg
  - smjpeg
  - smoothstreaming
  - sox
  - spx
  - spdif
  - srt
  - sup
  - swf
  - tee
  - 3g2
  - 3gp
  - mkvtimestamp_v2
  - truehd
  - tta
  - uncodedframecrc
  - vc1
  - vc1test
  - voc
  - w64
  - wav
  - webm
  - webm_dash_manifest
  - webm_chunk
  - webp
  - webvtt
  - wtv
  - wv
  - yuv4mpegpipe
  - alsa
  - fbdev
  - oss
  - pulse
  - sdl,sdl2
  - v4l2
  - xv
...
---
audio_codecs:
  - comfortnoise
  - s302m
  - aac
  - ac3
  - ac3_fixed
  - alac
  - dca
  - eac3
  - flac
  - g723_1
  - mlp
  - mp2
  - mp2fixed
  - nellymoser
  - opus
  - real_144
  - sonic
  - sonicls
  - truehd
  - tta
  - vorbis
  - wavpack
  - wmav1
  - wmav2
  - pcm_alaw
  - pcm_f32be
  - pcm_f32le
  - pcm_f64be
  - pcm_f64le
  - pcm_mulaw
  - pcm_s8
  - pcm_s8_planar
  - pcm_s16be
  - pcm_s16be_planar
  - pcm_s16le
  - pcm_s16le_planar
  - pcm_s24be
  - pcm_s24daud
  - pcm_s24le
  - pcm_s24le_planar
  - pcm_s32be
  - pcm_s32le
  - pcm_s32le_planar
  - pcm_s64be
  - pcm_s64le
  - pcm_u8
  - pcm_u16be
  - pcm_u16le
  - pcm_u24be
  - pcm_u24le
  - pcm_u32be
  - pcm_u32le
  - roq_dpcm
  - adpcm_adx
  - g722
  - g726
  - g726le
  - adpcm_ima_qt
  - adpcm_ima_wav
  - adpcm_ms
  - adpcm_swf
  - adpcm_yamaha
  - libmp3lame
  - libopus
  - libvorbis
...
---
video_codecs:
  - a64multi
  - a64multi5
  - alias_pix
  - amv
  - apng
  - asv1
  - asv2
  - avrp
  - avui
  - ayuv
  - bmp
  - cinepak
  - cljr
  - dnxhd
  - dpx
  - dvvideo
  - ffv1
  - ffvhuff
  - fits
  - flashsv
  - flashsv2
  - flv
  - gif
  - h261
  - h263
  - h263p
  - huffyuv
  - jpeg2000
  - jpegls
  - ljpeg
  - mjpeg
  - mpeg1video
  - mpeg2video
  - mpeg4
  - msmpeg4v2
  - msmpeg4
  - msvideo1
  - pam
  - pbm
  - pcx
  - pgm
  - pgmyuv
  - png
  - ppm
  - prores
  - prores_aw
  - prores_ks
  - qtrle
  - r10k
  - r210
  - rawvideo
  - roqvideo
  - rv10
  - rv20
  - sgi
  - snow
  - sunrast
  - svq1
  - targa
  - tiff
  - utvideo
  - v210
  - v308
  - v408
  - v410
  - vc2
  - wrapped_avframe
  - wmv1
  - wmv2
  - xbm
  - xface
  - xwd
  - y41p
  - yuv4
  - zlib
  - zmbv
  - libtheora
  - libvpx
  - libvpx-vp9
  - libx264
  - libx264rgb
  - libx265
  - h264_nvenc
  - nvenc
  - nvenc_h264
  - nvenc_hevc
  - hevc_nvenc
...
[Debug  ] <EncodeDock::EncodeDock> end 
[Debug  ] <JobsDock::JobsDock> begin 
[Debug  ] <JobsDock::JobsDock> end 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::readWindowSettings> begin 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::readWindowSettings> end 
[Debug  ] <LeapNetworkListener::start> begin 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::MainWindow> end 
[Debug  ] <Database::run> Database version is 1 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::GLWidget::initializeGL> begin 
[Info   ] <Mlt::GLWidget::initializeGL> OpenGL vendor "Intel Open Source Technology Center" 
[Info   ] <Mlt::GLWidget::initializeGL> OpenGL renderer "Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile " 
[Info   ] <Mlt::GLWidget::initializeGL> OpenGL threaded? false 
[Info   ] <Mlt::GLWidget::initializeGL> OpenGL ES? false 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::GLWidget::initializeGL> end 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "alpha_adjust" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Alpha Channel: Adjust" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "alpha_view" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Alpha Channel: View" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_balance" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Balance" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_bandpass" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Band Pass" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_basstreble" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Bass & Treble" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_channelcopy" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Copy Channel" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_compressor" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Compressor" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_delay" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Delay" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_expander" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Expander" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_fadein" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Fade In Audio" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_fadeout" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Fade Out Audio" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_gain" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Gain / Volume" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_highpass" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "High Pass" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_limiter" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Limiter" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_lowpass" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Low Pass" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_mono" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Downmix" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_mute" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Mute" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_normalize_1p" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Normalize: One Pass" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_normalize_2p" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Normalize: Two Pass" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_notch" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Notch" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_pan" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Pan" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_reverb" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Reverb" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "audio_swapchannels" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Swap Channels" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "bluescreen0r" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Chroma Key: Simple" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "blur" "meta_boxblur.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Blur" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "blur" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Blur" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "brightness" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Brightness" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "brightness" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Brightness" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "color" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Color Grading" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "color" "meta_frei0r_coloradj.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Color Grading" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "color" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Color Grading" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "contrast" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Contrast" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "contrast" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Contrast" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "crop" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Crop" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "crop" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Crop" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "dust" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Old Film: Dust" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "dynamictext" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Text" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "fadein_brightness" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Fade In Video" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "fadein_movit" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Fade In Video" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "fadeout_brightness" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Fade Out Video" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "fadeout_movit" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Fade Out Video" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "glow" "meta_frei0r.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Glow" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "glow" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Glow" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "grain" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Old Film: Grain" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "invert" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Invert Colors" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "keyspillm0pup" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Key Spill: Advanced" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "lenscorrection" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Lens Correction" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "lines" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Old Film: Scratches" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "lut3d" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "LUT (3D)" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "mask" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Mask" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "mirror" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Mirror" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "mirror" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Mirror" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "mosaic" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Mosaic" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "movit_diffusion" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Diffusion" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "oldfilm" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Old Film: Projector" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "opacity" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Opacity" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "opacity" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Opacity" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "rotate" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Rotate" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "saturation" "meta_frei0r.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Saturation" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "saturation" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Saturation" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "select0r" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Chroma Key: Advanced" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "sepia" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Sepia Tone" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "sharpen" "meta_frei0r.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Sharpen" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "sharpen" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Sharpen" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "size_position" "meta_affine.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Size and Position" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "size_position" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Size and Position" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "sketch" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Sketch" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "smartblur" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Reduce Noise" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "spectrum" "meta_spectrum.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Audio Spectrum Visualization" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "spillsuppress" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Key Spill: Simple" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "stabilize" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Stabilize" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "tcolor" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Old Film: Technocolor" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "vignette" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Vignette" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "vignette" "meta_oldfilm.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Vignette" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "wave" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Wave" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "webvfx" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Overlay HTML" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "webvfx_circular_frame" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Circular Frame (HTML)" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "webvfx_ruttetraizer" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "Rutt-Etra-Izer (HTML)" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "webvfx_threejs_text" "meta.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "3D Text (HTML)" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "white" "meta_frei0r.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "White Balance" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> reading filter metadata "white" "meta_movit.qml" 
[Debug  ] <FilterController::loadFilterMetadata> added filter "White Balance" 
[Warning] <> libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
[Debug  ] <LeapNetworkListener::onDisconnected> Disconnected from Leap Motion 
[Debug  ] <LeapNetworkListener::onError> Leap Motion WebSocket error: "Connection refused" 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::open> "/home/brodie/snap/shotcut/22/.local/share/Meltytech/Shotcut/__untitled__.mlt" 
[Debug  ] <MltXmlChecker::MltXmlChecker> decimal point '.' 
[Debug  ] <MltXmlChecker::check> begin 
[Debug  ] <MltXmlChecker::check> end 
[Info   ] <MainWindow::showStatusMessage> "Checking for upgrade..." 
[Debug  ] <MainWindow::onUpgradeCheckFinished> response:  "{\n  \"version_number\": 180503,\n  \"version_string\": \"18.05.03\",\n  \"url\": \"https://shotcut.org/blog/new-release-1805/\"\n}\n" 
[Info   ] <MainWindow::showStatusMessage> "You are running the latest version of Shotcut." 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::GLWidget::~GLWidget> begin 
[Debug  ] <Mlt::FrameRenderer::cleanup> begin
```